# in php how to call img with user id

Tags: php

img name is $user->id.jpg or 543.jpg

```
<?php 
    $logo = "<img src='images/jbjobs/$user->id.jpg'>";
?>
```

after here

```
$logo = "<img src='images/jbjobs/
```

I dont know what to do and I have to escape ' or ".

Answer (score 3):

Any of the following will do:

```
$logo = "<img src='images/jbjobs/{$user->id}.jpg'>";
$logo = "<img src='images/jbjobs/".$user->id.".jpg'>";
```

Comment: $logo = "<img src='images/jbjobs/".$user->id.".jpg'>"; worked thank you everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php 

$logo = "<img src='images/jbjobs/{$user->id}.jpg'>"; // {} is like concatenate 

?>
```

Comment: <?php 

$logo = "<img src='images/jbjobs/{$user->id.jpg}'>";

?>
 did not work